# how can i link my javascript file with html???? I think i have linked properly but not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, linker

WHAT is problem in linking javascript code to html code???
 my html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>PARUL</title>
    <script  src="script.js"></script>
    <script>
    console.log(x)
    </script>


</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

my javascript code:

```
var x="hello world";
```

Comment: Write click in your browser and go to view page source, click there on script.js and see if it is linked correctly?

Comment: What makes you think "it's not working"?

Comment: Do you have dev tools console open in the browser when you load this page?

Comment: If it's linked then right click on browser click on "Inspect" then go to "console" tab and you can view the value of x there

Comment: Assuming your JavaScript code is in the same directory as your html file, that it is in a file named named script.js, this should work. Please confirm your browser console does not contain "Hello World", follow the instructions in @TufailAhmad's comment.

Answer (score 0):

You have already linked your HTML code with your JS file.
Follow these steps :

1. Right click on your mouse and you will get the option `Inspect` at the bottom.
2. Click on it and you will get the developer tool having multiple tabs in it like `Elements`,`Console`,etc.
3. You just need to click on the `Console` tab. Then you will able to see the output which you have given the statement `console.log("")`